# Star wars young adult book with Shadow Academy

Tags: story-identification, star-wars

In the 1990's my mom gave me a paperback Star Wars book. It was geared towards young adults and centered around a "Shadow Academy" that taught both the light and dark side of the force to teenagers.

One of the characters was named Jay or Jason or Jayson or J'son, etc.

Comment: Could it just literally be [*Shadow Academy*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Young_Jedi_Knights:_Shadow_Academy)? With Jacen Solo?

Comment: @Adamant Yes, I think that's right. I couldn't think of that term until I was writing the question.

Comment: @Adamant Oh, wait, Jacen *Solo*?? So you're saying it's basically Ky'lo Ren?

Comment: Have you not read Legends in a while? :P

Comment: @Adamant It was the only Star Wars book I ever read until the past 3 months. In the past 3 months I've listened to a ton of dark side audiobooks from Legends, but I couldn't find this one on Audible.

Comment: I read this one once at a Salvation Army. I think it's very popular.

Comment: @Adamant You can make that an answer if you want and I will accept it. It's still my favorite Star Wars book, though Darth Bane books were a close 2nd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### *[Young Jedi Knights: Shadow Academy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Young_Jedi_Knights:_Shadow_Academy)*

The character that you're thinking of is Jacen Solo.

From Wookieepedia:

> While on a tour of Lando Calrissian's GemDiver Station, **Jacen**, Jaina,
>   Lowbacca, and Em Teedee are caught in the middle of an Imperial raid
>   and kidnapped. After being informed of what happened by Lando, Luke
>   Skywalker embarks upon a rescue mission in search of the missing Jedi
>   trainees. Feeling guilty because she was not with her friends and
>   therefore could not help them, Tenel Ka accompanies him.

And of course, there is a "Shadow Academy":

> Meanwhile, aboard an assault shuttle that figured prominently in the
>   attack on GemDiver Station, the twins and Lowbacca meet Tamith Kai,
>   the woman who led the attack. **The students learn from her that their
>   destination is the "Shadow Academy" where they will be trained to use
>   the dark side of the Force in the service of the Second Imperium.** Once
>   they arrive at their destination, Brakiss, one of Luke's former
>   students and the headmaster of the Shadow Academy greets them and
>   reiterates most of what Tamith Kai told them. Jacen, Jaina and
>   Lowbacca are then confined to their own separate cells.

Comment: Was the Rule of 2 out the window at this point? Or was it cool because they were Dark Jedi instead of Sith?

Comment: @Hack-R - Most likely the latter.

Comment: Yeah, the books more or less rule that Dark Jedi are not Sith. The Rebels cartoons continued that trend with the Sith Inquisitors.